# jScrollPane not working correctly within textareas

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

I had a search around to see how to get [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) working with `textareas` and found this: http://www.christianchown.com/blog/a-custom-jquery-scrollbar-in-a-textarea/

You can see a working example here: http://www.christianchown.com/demo/jScrollPaneTextarea.html

However in my own testing I haven't been able to get it working right for some reason; scroll bars always seem to show even when not needed (when it first loads) and when it does need them after typing it just loads the standard scroll bars as well.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Fndg3/7/

What am I missing here?

Comment: The "working example" looks horrible here in Chrome on Windows.

Comment: It looks fine for me in Firefox/Window, but I noticed if I start playing with it it starts `behaving badly'; so maybe it's not the best option after all. :(

Comment: Ok, just looked at it on Chrome and you are right, looks terrible.

Comment: When the 'working example' site changes, this question becomes useless. Please include everything we need to reproduce your problem in the question itself (not in a fiddle or link). The fiddle can be supplementary, but if someone comes to this page and you're asking about a problem you have with code you've written, we should see code in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you just have to scroll a DIV that includes a textfield (and turn off scrollbars of the textfield, too ...). and maybe try another scroll script, i tested some and found that "http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/" is the most flexible and compatible.

Comment: Thanks for the link; looks good. Wish I had seen this before I had implemented the other scroll bar plugin with everything else though haha